# My cURL request is working from a server but not from another

Tags: curl, server, connection-timeout

I've got a problem with a cURL request from a provider. 
We try to do conversational SMS and we got a Webhook page that get the informations when a costumer answer a SMS.

The request sent by the provider to our server don't trigger our webhook page (Connection timed out).

However, when I try to do the exactly same request from another external server, it works perfectly.

This is the request :

```
curl -v -m 10 -X POST "mywebhookURL" -d '{"snapshotId":1354567,"accountId":"560a643cf2817caf0ed9","campaignId":"5e5780004e57014a4bb2a","contact":{"id":"5d28884406b97c176f8fc","identifier":"","countryCode":33},"replyMessage": "30000","event": "reply","eventDate": 1473429780000}'
```

My provider gets this answer :

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying IP Address...
*   Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
*   Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
```

From another server :

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying IP Address...
*   TCP_NODELAY set
*   Connected to Server URL (IP Address) port 443 (#0)
```

Why should I have two different answers for the exactly same cURL request from two different servers to the same server URL ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There may be many reasons that an URL is accessible from one server and from another it is not

1. Different rules on server firewal
2. Different network configuration on clients (DNS, routing)
3. Clients may use some proxy
4. One client has very slow network

Try to narrow down the problem. I would start from:

1. call `ping server_ip` from both clients
2. call `ping server_name` from both clients

and see if there is a difference between above commands executed on both clients.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. My provider found the problem. He can't read our certificates so the request was blocking at this point. We found a way to avoid to problem. We made the request from the provider) go to another server (where the problem is not appearing) and redirect the request to our server where the request was blocking.